# Drag N Drop event when drop completes

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dojo

I have a project using `dijit/Tree` and `dijit/tree/dndSource` where the user can move tree items using drag and drop to make changes.  I am using dojo release 1.10.4See jsfiddle here

[Dojo Tree w/drag and drop](https://jsfiddle.net/goinoff/xp9ct4v5/)

I need to have a notification when the drop is complete.  It seems like `onDndDrop` would be the obvious place to trap this event but the documentation says that it's not a good idea to mess with this event:

[dojo/dnd documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html#source)

From the doc above...

Topic processors

Following topic listeners are defined: onDndSourceOver, onDndStart, **onDndDrop**, onDndCancel. These topics are published by the Manager. If you want to override topic listeners, please read Summary of topics.

[Summary of topics](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html#summary-of-topics)

Warning: in most cases you want to use events. Topics are low-level constructs, which are used internally and generally should not be used for customization.

--------- end doc -----------

So, how can I get notification of when the drop completes so I can update some items on the server side using ajax?? `onDndDrop` event which is available using `dijit/tree/dndSource` object is what I need but the doc says one shouldn't mess with it.  In my jsfiddle example above, I have it commented out `//onDndDrop: treeDropEvt,` on the `tree` object creation. If you add this to the tree creation, `treeDropEvt` get called when the user moves a tree item to another location in the tree but errors can be seen in the console and the move doesn't happen.

If I have to use `onDndDrop` event, how do I go about creating it so I receive no errors and it functions normally???

Answer (score 1):

I do the thing you want to do in the `pasteItem` function of the `TreeStoreModel`. TreeStoreModel is the store of the Dojo Tree.

```
 var memoryStore = new Memory({
            data: [{
               id: "root",
               name: "ROOT",
               loaded: true
            }, ],
            getChildren: function(object) {
               return this.query({
                  parent: object.id
               });
            },
            clearOnClose:true
         });

var myStore = new Observable(memoryStore);

 var myModel = new TreeStoreModel({
                store: myStore,
                query: {
                   id: "root"
                },
                labelAttr: "label",
                pasteItem: function(child, oldParent, newParent, copy, insertIndex) {
                   // SEND NOTIFICATION, DO QUERIES
                }
             });

var tree = new Tree({
            model: myModel,
            dndController: dndSource
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stefano, will check this out..Isn't `TreeStoreModel` deprecated??  Will check to see if there is a pasteItem for `ObjectStoreModel`??

Comment: Sincerely I don't know if it is deprecated. `ObjectStoreModel` has also pasteItem, try that. [Doc] (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel.html)

Answer (score 0):

After posting the problem above, I found a solution using `topic`.  See my update jsfiddle here:

[Monitor onDrop event using topic](https://jsfiddle.net/goinoff/m4p6vc4w/)

add `"dojo/topic"` to the `require` line.

`topic.subscribe("/dnd/drop",treeDropEvt2);`

```
function treeDropEvt2(source, nodes, copy, target) {
  console.log('treeDropEvt2');
  console.dir(source);
  console.dir(nodes);
  console.dir(copy);
  console.dir(target);
}
```

After making these changes to my project, everything works OK without errors and I can now make ajax call back to the server during a drop event. Note below that this event fires during the beginning of a drop and not when it's finished.

**UPDATE**

Using this method to fire `treeDropEvt2` during a drop seems to be at the beginning of the drop instead of after the drop completes. Not sure why getting notification of a finished drop is such a pain?? very frustrating..